# "in places recommendation" vs. "in the recommendation of places"

Tags: prepositions, syntax, nominalization

When I need to say "to use something to recommend a place", what is the correct phrasing?

> **in the** recommendation of places

or

> **in** places recommendation

Here is the full context (it's the abstract of my college final assignment):

> *Study on the use of multiobjective optimization in commercial establishments recommendation*.

I'm in doubt about that last phrase.

Comment: Sorry, we don't do proofreading here on ELL. It would use up a lot of the answerers' time and defocus the site. Have a look [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/263/6700) for a couple suggestions where you might be able to get your whole abstract checked. Good luck.

Comment: I don't want you to check the whole abstract. It's just a question about the use of "in" or "in the". I think you misunderstood my question or I explained it wrong.

Comment: “in establishments recommendation” in the title is not in either of your examples. Changing words after "in" or "in the" invalidates the comparison.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. If you can reword it so it's more clearly a question about "in" vs. "in the", then it will fit well on ELL. Or I can try to reword it in a few minutes, when I get to a computer with a nicer keyboard. :)

Comment: I just rewrote the entire question. Hope it's better now

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb, use *VERB-derived-NOUN **of** X* when *X* is the Patient (Object) of *VERB* and *X**'s** VERB-derived-NOUN* when *X* is the Agent (Subject) of *VERB*.

> *My recommendation* implies<sup>†</sup> that I made the recommendation.
>   *Recommendation of me* implies<sup>†</sup> that someone recommended me.

If both the Agent and the Patient are present in the "nominal" clause, this is obligatory: *My recommendation of the restaurant*, not *The restaurant's recommendation of me* (unless I'm applying at another establishment for a job as a waiter).

In other circumstances you can sometimes get away with ignoring the rule, particularly if the semantics of the situation make the meaning clear. But I advise you to avoid permitting yourself that license, which makes your sentences harder to parse.

So make it

> Study on the use of multiobjective optimization in recommendation of commercial establishments

And,as J.R. points out, a *the* in there is possible, maybe even desirable, if there is no other determiner present:

> ... in the recommendation of ...

More generally, however, I advise you to avoid this sort of hypernominalization altogether; it's tedious to read and often unintelligible. Stick as close to any underlying verbiness as possible: if your context won't permit a frank finite verb or infinitive, use a gerund.

> Study on the use of multiobjective optimization in **recommending** commercial establishments *or, since* study *and* use *are superfluous in what appears to be a title*
>
> Multiobjective optimization in recommending commercial establishments *or even (hazarding a guess about what* multiobjective optimization *means*)
>
> Optimizing for multiple objectives in recommending commercial establishments

---

<sup>†</sup>Technically this should be *implicates*: this is a 'cancellable' implicature, not an inviolable entailment. But I'm still not comfortable with that neologistic use of *implicate*.

Comment: I think I might insert a definite article: _Study on the use of multiobjective optimization in **the** recommendation of commercial establishments._

Comment: @J.R. It's certainly not out of the question; I have no idea what people who write and read papers with that sort of title prefer.